# CSS Как корректно оформить поиск?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ui

[image: Пример]
Помогите с оптимальной настройкой (концепцией) открывающегося поиска по клику:

- Зелёная иконка - `class="label"`. При нажатии едет вправо и становится крестиком (функция: открыть - закрыть).
- Синяя иконка (скрыта до клика) - `class="action"`, выполняет роль Enter.
- Форма для вставки поискового запроса - `input id="search"`.

```html
<div class="field search">
  <label class="label" for="search" data-role="minisearch-label"></label>
  <div class="control">
      <input id="search" class="search-autocomplete">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?>" class="action search">
    </button>
</div>

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .label {
      float: left;

  .label.active+.control input{
      position: static;
  }

  input {
      left: -300%;
      margin: 15px 0;
      position: absolute;
  }
}

//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  .label {
      position: absolute;
  }

  .label.active+.control input{
      width: 250px;
  }

  input {
      padding: 0;
      position: static;
      margin: 0;
      width: 0;
  }
}
```

Работа JS (Jquery):

1. При нажатии на иконку поиска `label class="label"`, меняет класс `class="label active"`.
2. А окно поиска `input id="search"` меняется на `id="search active"`.
3. Кнопка закрытия не обязательна. В Jquery прописано закрытие при потере фокуса.

PS. Прошу помочь в рамках вопроса и данных в нём.
Тут возникает ряд проблем: корректная подмена иконок, но это выполнимо с помощью `z-index`. Другая важная проблема, если задавать для input `width: 0`, перестаёт работать клик на планшетах.

Comment: Думаю, кнопка "закрыть" - лишняя. Посмотрите на поиск в шапке этого сайта. Поиск закрывается, как только поле теряет фокус.

Answer (score 4):

Как например:

```js
$('.search__trigger').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var
    $this = $(this),
     ico  = $this.find('.fa'),
     form = $this.closest('.search__form');
  
  if(!form.hasClass('open')){
    form.addClass('open');
    ico.toggleClass('fa-search fa-close');
  }else {
    form.removeClass('open');
    ico.toggleClass('fa-close fa-search');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.search__trigger,
.search__enter {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}

.search__input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: auto;  
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009eba;
  
}

.search__trigger {
  color: #77ab46;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.search__enter {
  color: #009eba;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
}

.search__input-wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0%;  
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
}

.open .search__input-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.open .search__trigger {
  left: 92%;
}


.open .search__enter {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  

  
  <form class="search__form">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#" class="search__trigger">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>

      <label for="search" class="search__input-wrap">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="search__input">
      </label>

      <button type="submit" class="search__enter">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! К сожалению разметка шаблона другая и jquery работает иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, кнопка «закрыть» — лишняя. Посмотрите на поиск в шапке этого сайта. Поиск закрывается, как только поле теряет фокус.

Если отказаться от этой кнопки, то можно собрать вариант на чистом CSS, без скриптов. Чтобы поиск закрылся, достаточно щёлкнуть мышью за его пределами:

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/awxjdv

```css
.search__control {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
}
.search__control:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #11accf;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
}
.search__control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #11accf !important; }
.search__control::-moz-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control:-moz-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control::placeholder { color: #11accf; }

.search__label {
  color: #84b559;
  cursor: pointer;  
  float: left;
  margin-right: 9px;
}
.search__control:focus + .search__label {
  color: #11accf;
  cursor: auto;
}
.search__control,
.search__label {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
       -o-transition: all .4s ease;
          transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input class="search__control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <label class="search__label" for="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Аналогичный вариант можно применить и к другому расположению лейбла и поля, но тогда не удастся перекрашивать лейбл с помощью [соседних селекторов](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent):

```css
.search__control input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
}
.search__control input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #11accf;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
}
.search__control input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #11accf !important; }
.search__control input::-moz-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control input:-moz-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #11accf; }
.search__control input::placeholder { color: #11accf; }

.search__label {
  color: #11accf;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 9px;
}
.search__control input,
.search__label {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
       -o-transition: all .4s ease;
          transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <label class="search__label" for="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
  <div class="search__control">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Благодарю! Но тут задача как упорядочить кнопки "Открыть" и "Интер" в рамках данной html разметки и кода Jquery. Это актуально для очень большого сообщество так как готовые jquery и html являются стандартным шаблоном платформы Magento 2. К сожалению пока не смог найти решения с помощью css... Тут в принципе jquery не важен в ответе. А именно ответ на вопрос как скрыть одну кнопку за другой и обратно.

Comment: Менял разметку, чтобы перекрашивать иконку с&nbsp;помощью [соседних селекторов](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent). Без перекрашивания можно оставить другую разметку.

Comment: Добавил вариант решения для вашего расположения блоков.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в таком варианте отсутствует button type="submit", а по факту она есть и она находится над label class="label" (имеется ввиду визуализация, а не html). Из-за этого не могу найти решение, как спрятать корректно button type="submit" до нажатия label class="label". Сейчас получается они обе видны...

Comment: На рисунке в вопросе где находится кнопка `submit`? Что мешает добавить блок с этой кнопкой после блока с полем поиска?

Comment: `submit` внизу синяя. Как вариант да. Решение при этой разметке, изначально назначить для `submit  z-index: -1;` а как только поле становится активным, назначается `z-index: 4;` .

Comment: Cтолкнулся с проблемой впервые, пробовал сделать меняющуюся ширину от 0 до 200px, перестаёт работать клик на айпаде. Получается аномалия какая-то с шириной width: 0, когда блок не имеет ширины и padding, то он будто вылетает из потока и не знает куда и где распахнутся. Причем то же самое и в моём варианте. Возможно есть какие-то правила, что блок при абсолютной нулевой ширине работает не корректно? Но как только задаю padding, то всё работает, но padding не нужен для композиции...