# Как ввести текст, если поле видно, только когда иконка получает фокус?

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент с иконкой **search** от font-awesome, который пропадает при получении фокуса, и вместо него появляется поле поиска. Но ввести текст не удаётся: иконка теряет фокус, и поле ввода сворачивается.

Каким образом можно ввести текст в поле?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clear,
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

header .name {
  float: left;
}

header .search {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .2s linear;
}

.search:focus {
  width: 300px;
}

.fa-search {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.search:focus>.fa-search {
  display: none;
}

.insearch {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<header class="clear">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>kinOblomoff.net</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="search" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <form action="">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Введите фразу для поиска" class="insearch" tabindex="-2">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: пример смотреть на полном экране : мобильную версию ни делал ещё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если связать между собой метку `label` и поле `input`, то метка будет передавать фокус полю ввода. Есть [два способа](https://webref.ru/html/label) это сделать:

1. расположить `input` внутри `label`;
2. добавить полю идентификатор `id`, а метке — атрибут `for`.

Используем второй способ, потому что нам нужно показывать поле и метку по очереди, а не одновременно.

И расположим метку сразу после поля, чтобы задавать её стиль через [соседние селекторы](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent).

```
<input class="search__control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
<label class="search__label" for="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
```

Работает это так:

1. Сначала показываем только метку, а поле прячем с помощью `width: 0;` и прозрачных границ. Чтобы пользователю было понятнее, чего от него ждут, превращаем курсор над меткой в тыкающий перст.
2. Когда пользователь нажимает на иконку, фокус достаётся полю, — благодаря его связи с меткой. Пользуемся этим, чтобы поменять стили поля через [псевдокласс `:focus`](https://webref.ru/css/focus). А до стилей метки добираемся через соседние селекторы:

```css
.search__control:focus {
  ...
}
.search__control:focus + .search__label {
  ...
}
```

Получится, например, так: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/gxVvqG

```css
.sitename {
  float: left;
}
.search {
  float: right;
}
.search__control {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
       -o-transition: all .4s ease;
          transition: all .4s ease;
}
.search__control:focus {
  border-color: black;
  outline: none;
  width: 120px;
}

.search__label {
  cursor: pointer;  
  float: left;
}
.search__control:focus + .search__label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="sitename">Site Name</div>
  <div class="search">
    <form action="">
      <input class="search__control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <label class="search__label" for="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский [В этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693106/208926) делал вариант с перекрашиванием иконки и постепенным появлением поля поиска. Может быть, пригодится как идея.

Comment: Не понятно как это работает ... каким образом label привязан к input ?

Comment: Есть [два способа](https://webref.ru/html/label): когда input внутри label и когда им добавлены атрибуты (инпуту `id`, а лейблу `for`). Здесь использован второй, чтобы менять стиль лейбла через [соседние селекторы](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent).

Comment: для меня именно эта тема была всегда не понятной , спс за пояснения буду работать над этим ...

Comment: Gleb о меня дошло как ... спасибо огромное

Comment: Добавил пояснений в ответ. Спасибо за вопрос: самому было полезно углубиться в механику.