# Как передать на :focus событие?

Tags: css3, html5, события

[Это вопрос к сожалению в этом контексте не помог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716511/33274)

Как в этом случае передать событие на элемент который появляется по событию :`focus`?

[Этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829081/33274) заинтересовал своей не ординарностью как ответ который автор выбрал как Лучший т.е решение меня не устроил

Я смоделировал Q&A и двумя комментариям который один вложен в другой

Идея в том что и у автора подобного вопроса, при клике на один блок закрыть рядом стоящий но по событию :focus который откроется

Моя реализация (не люблю портянки пример под спойлером):

```js
$("span.trigger").on("click", function() {
  $(".cabinet").toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.ask {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ask h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.ask p {
  width: 90%;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.user-profile {
  padding: 10px;
  outline-width: 0.5px;
  outline-color: #ccc;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

.cabinet {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.cabinet span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cabinet span:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.ask img {
  margin: 14px 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

ul {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.as-panel {}

.as-panel div,
.as-panel span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-family: georgia;
}

.as-panel div span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: orange;
}

.as1 {
  position: relative;
}

.as1 .com {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.as1:focus .labelcom>.com {
  visibility: visible;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
}

li {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .ask {
    zoom: 0.9;
  }
  .ask h2 {
    font-size: 115%;
  }
  .user-profile span {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .ask p {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .ask h2 {
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .user-profile span {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .ask p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:420px) {
  .ask h2 {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .ask img {
    display: none;
  }
  .ask p {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .user-profile {
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .user-profile span {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .cabinet {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cabinet span {
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  span.trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
  span.trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 6px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 2px auto;
  }
  .show {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@media (max-width:350px) {}
```

```html
<div class="ask">
  <h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, vitae?
  </h2>
  <div class="user-profile clear">
    <span>name family</span>
    <span>category</span>
    <span>guru(2100)</span>
    <span>2018.05.20</span>
    <span class="trigger">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </span>
    <div class="cabinet">
      <span>cabinet</span>
      <span>profile</span>
      <span>logout</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70" alt="">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, sint ipsa, id voluptate minus distinctio explicabo sequi totam aliquam autem repellat nesciunt maiores quasi? Vel exercitationem hic, ipsum adipisci saepe modi quod reprehenderit officiis
    placeat nihil, maxime similique molestias illo? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum quis atque reiciendis magnam et excepturi ab neque quidem iste dignissimos.
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="answer">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, temporibus! </span>
    <div class="as-panel">
      <div class="as1" tabindex="-1"><span>answers</span>
        <label class="labelcom" for="com">
           <div id="com" class="com">
             <form action="">
               <textarea></textarea>
               <input type="submit">
             </form>
             </div>
            </label>
      </div>
      <div>like</div>
      <div>alert</div>
    </div>
    <li class="answer">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, temporibus! </span>
      <div class="as-panel">
        <div class="as1" tabindex="-1"><span>answers</span>
          <label class="labelcom" for="com">
             <div id="com" class="com">
               <form action="">
                 <textarea></textarea>
                 <input type="submit">
               </form>
               </div>
              </label>
        </div>
        <div>like</div>
        <div>alert</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как в этом случае передать событие на **focus** элемент ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Желательно без jQuery, javascript** **на чистом css3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо чтобы не скрывался input открытый по :focus, то у меня работает если поменять:

```
.as1:focus .labelcom>.com {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

на:

```
.as1:focus .labelcom>.com, .com:hover{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Надеюсь я понял Ваш вопрос

Comment: в принципе.... подходит ... только `hover` смущает

Comment: можешь добавить `.com:focus-within` через запятую. Тогда не будет пропадать при фокусе на `textarea`.

Comment: это 100% то что надо .... ты гений